# Read Write Performance is halved when accessing a Shared drive on a VM

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, smb

Seeing very high Latency on the Shared drives of a VM as opposed to the local drives. 
The local drives on the VM shows a slight but negligible reduction in the Read Write speeds but the Latency on the Shared drives in the VM is more than double that of the local drives.

Running Server 2012 R2, the HD is running off an SATA connection but I'm unsure of the specific specs. It's on a GigE network connecting to the shares.

SMB is optimized as well.

Any advice on decreasing the latency would be greatly appreciated. Or thoughts on why the latency for the shares are so high.

Also Larger files create less latency than many small files.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your virtual machine environment is experiencing network packet loss. As the first troubleshooting step, I would look into performing a packet loss review and see if your retransmits are too high.

Also, do you have any software firewalls or IDS systems on the virtualized server?